# Can the computer find a word in a list from the input?

Tags: python

I am trying to make a chatbot. I have created a list of keywords. If the user says hello or another word in the list, it will reply.

```
greeting_words = ["hi", "hey", "hello", "morning", "afternoon", "evening", "good morning", "good afternoon", "good evening"]
greeting_responses = ['hi', 'hey', 'hello' ]

human = input("")
```

If the user says a word in the greeting_words list, the computer responds with 1 word from the greeting_responses list.

How do I get the computer to look for a word in a list?

Comment: What have you tried? Which of the 3 responses should the computer user?

Comment: "How do I get the computer to look for a word *in* a list?" Use `in`?

Comment: Just one of them

Comment: It's literally `human in greeting_words`…

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import random

human = input()

if human in greeting_words:
    print(random.choice(greeting_responses))
```

Comment: @Harrison If they were using Python 2, `input()` would have had to have been `raw_input()`.

Comment: @Harrison Perfect. Thanks.